# Sending Authentication information to a web service

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, security

We are designing a system where a WPF client will call both WCF services and Java web services.

What we are wondering is how we should send the authentication information such that it is compatibile with both the Microsoft and Java web services.

All user are logged into a Windows Active Directory.

Some possibilities are Kerberos, SAML, WIF ... Can anyone make a recomendation on what we should use?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into libraries built around [JAAS and LDAP](http://jaaslounge.sourceforge.net/loginmodules.html).